# Transfer a file of any type in 1k chunks over HTTP

Tags: php, binaryfiles

I need to transfer files of any type or size over HTTP/GET in ~1k chunks. The resulting file hash needs to match the source file. This needs to be done in native PHP without any special tools. I have a basic strategy but I'm getting odd results. This proof of concept just copies the file locally.

CODE

```
<?php

    $input="/home/lm1/Music/Ellise - Feeling Something Bad.mp3";
    $a=pathinfo($input);
    $output=$a["basename"];

    echo "\n> ".md5_file($input);
    $fp=fopen($input,'rb');

    if ($fp) {

        while(!feof($fp)) {
            $buffer=base64_encode(fread($fp,1024));
            // echo "\n\n".md5($buffer);
            write($output,$buffer);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        echo "\n> ".md5_file($output);
        echo "\n";
        
    }   
    
    function write($file,$buffer) { 
        // echo "\n".md5($buffer);
        $fp = fopen($file, 'ab');
        fwrite($fp, base64_decode($buffer));
        fclose($fp);    
    }   
    
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
> d31e102b1cae9c73bbf5a12615a8ea36
> 9f03f6c88ed61c07cb534922d6d31864
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fread` already advances the file pointer position, so there's no need to keep track of it. Same with `frwite`, so consecutive calls automatically append to the given file. Thus, you could simplify your approach to (code adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18497531/3323348) on how to efficiently write a large input stream to a file):

```php
$src  = "a.test";
$dest = "b.test";

$fp_src = fopen($src, 'rb');

if ($fp_src) {
    
    $fp_dest     = fopen($dest, 'wb');
    $buffer_size = 1024;

    while(!feof($fp_src)) {
        
        fwrite($fp_dest, fread($fp_src, $buffer_size));
    }

    fclose($fp_src);
    fclose($fp_dest);

    echo md5_file($src)."\n";  // 88e4af2f85080a280e7f00e50d96b7f7
    echo md5_file($dest)."\n"; // 88e4af2f85080a280e7f00e50d96b7f7
}
```

If you want to keep both processes separated, you'd do:

```
$src  = "a.test";
$dest = "b.test";

if (file_exists($dest)) {

    unlink($dest); // So we don't append to an existing file
}

$fp = fopen($src,'rb');

if ($fp) {

    while(!feof($fp)){

        $buffer = base64_encode(fread($fp, 1024));
        write($dest, $buffer);
    } 

    fclose($fp);
}

function write($file, $buffer) { 
    
    $fp = fopen($file, 'ab');

    fwrite($fp, base64_decode($buffer));
    fclose($fp);    
}   

echo md5_file($src)."\n";  // 88e4af2f85080a280e7f00e50d96b7f7
echo md5_file($dest)."\n"; // 88e4af2f85080a280e7f00e50d96b7f7
```

As for how to stream files over HTTP, you might want to have a look at:

- [Streaming a large file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914912/streaming-a-large-file-using-php)

Comment: I was able to improve the code dramatically based on your example, thanks. But in my case the read and write will occur on different systems. When I separate read/write and base64 the buffers, they seem to match during but the resulting file is much larger and of course has a different hash.

Comment: I've extended my answer a bit, so my second example should be pretty close to your code now  - the only thing I really changed was to check if the destination file exists & delete it if it does. I totally missed that at first, maybe you did, too?

Comment: lol yes I did! Works like a charm, thanks.